# Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am trying to load url in iframe.I am getting the error  Refused to display  in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.Can anybody tell how to overcome this error

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the URL you are trying to load?

Comment: You can't.  That's what the X-Frame-Options header is for: it allows website owners to prevent others framing their site.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, not for just any URL, however, if you own/can get in contact with the owner of the site, then you/they can allow your site to display the theirs in an `<iframe>`:

[The X-Frame-Options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)

Answer (score -3):

I disabled my antivirus. And it worked.

Comment: Antivirus programs do not usually do this, and even if they did, disabling your own antivirus won't make your site start working for other people.